# React: Remove default value when user starts typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

lets say we have a text box (I am using react with formik and material ui) that will accept a price (a floating point number). When loaded, the field has a default value of 0. As soon as the user enter a number by hand the default value should be cleared and the manually entered value should take its place instead.

value: 0 -> user enters 1 -> value: 1

That's fine so far, where I struggle is if I wish to preserve the floating point.

value: 0 -> user enters 1 -> value: 1 -> user enters . (floating point) -> value: 1. -> user enters 0 -> value 1

In order to illustrate it better, I've put together this [CodeSandbox](http://ttps://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-swanson-06927).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the conversion from string to Number with `const newValue = Number(event.target.value);`

Since `1` and `1.0` are equivalent numerically, there is no good way to preserve the exact number of 0s the user put in. If you want to do that, you could consider leaving it as a string and only converting back to a number when you want to do some math to it.

Also, since you're working with prices, you could look at `Number.toFixed()` to for example always place 2 decimal places at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I wrote your new `NuberFormField.js` component:

```
import * as React from "react";

import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";

export const NumberFormField = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors },
  inputProps,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue, setFieldTouched } = useFormikContext();

  field.onChange = event => {
    const newValue = event.target.value; // This line is your bottleneck
    setFieldValue(field.name, newValue);
    setFieldTouched(field.name, true);
    console.log("new val", newValue, field.name);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      inputProps={{
        ...inputProps,
        type: "number"
       }}
      InputProps={{
        ...field,
        ...inputProps
      }}
    />
  );
};
```